# Using PHP script with MEAN stack

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mean-stack

This is my first time building a website with the MEAN stack. One of the things I would like to do is the ability to push notifications to a companion iOS mobile app, which uses the website as a backend.

I followed this tutorial for a PHP script that could push notifications: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Now would it be possible to incorporate that script in the MEAN stack somehow, basically have it run PHP. If not, does anyone have recommendations for how to use the MEAN stack with iOS push notifications.

Thanks